# Laravel and jquery datatable delete row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I'm using laravel 5.2, Jquery 1.10 and MYSQL 5.7.

I'm using RESTful services in laravel for my message model.

I am trying to render a list of messages in a Jquery datatable and provide a delete button on each row which when pressed should fire the destroy method on MessageController.php, deleting the row then re-loading the message index page to display the updated datatable.

The datatable is being generated correctly initially but the delete button does not fire the delete method on the controller.  I'm assuming my ajax code for generating the delete button must be wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

My datatable ajax script is-

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#message_table').DataTable({

        "searchable": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/message",
            "type": "POST",
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id"},
            { "data": "subject",
                "render": function(data,type,row,meta) {
                    return '<a href="/message/'+row.id+'">'+data+'</a>';
                }
            },
            { "data": "created_at",
                "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                    // instantiate a moment object and hand it the string date
                    var d = moment(data);
                    var month = d.month() +1 < 10 ? "0" + (d.month() +1) : d.month() +1;
                    var day = d.date()  < 10 ? "0" + (d.date()): d.date();
                    return month + "/" + day + "/" + d.year();
                }
            },
            {"defaultContent": "null", "render": function(data,type,row,meta) {
                return '<button action="' + $(location).attr('protocol') + $(location).attr('host') + '/message/'+row.id+ '"' + 'name="_method"' + 'method="post"' +'type="submit"' + 'value="Delete"'+'>'+ 'Delete</button>';
            }
            }
        ]
    });
} );
```

---

The generated HTML for the delete button from the last function is-

```
<button action="http:localhost:8000/message/6" name="_method" method="post" type="submit" value="Delete">Delete</button>
```

Message controller delete method-

```
   public function destroy($id)
{
    Message::destroy($id);

    return Redirect::route('message.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using laravel's restful controller then the destroy method is by `delete` http method. So the best option is to create small form like:

```
<form action="http:localhost:8000/message/6" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Button HTML now working.  Now getting a MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 exception.  405 error. Strange as the delete route exists and works on another blade.

Comment: Sorted.  Needed to add the csrf token to the delete http method. Laravel rocks!